# Does SqlDataAdapter Requires open connection To Execute Sql Command

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, ado

Does SqlDataAdapter Requires open connection To Execute Sql Command ?

see below :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strconn);            
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from EmpDetails", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);           
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();           
        da.Fill(ds);           
        GV_Data.DataSource = ds;
        GV_Data.DataBind();
    }
```

anyone have a clue about this ?

Comment: Did you note anything gone strange?

Answer (score 1):

No. A DataAdapter will open a closed connection automatically, before it fills a dataset/table. It will also return the connection to the state it was before the fill operation